# What's the variation of entropy of an irreversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

I'm studying entropy, in particular the increase of entropy principle, and I have a doubt about the entropy variation of an irreversible transformation.

If I have two thermodynamic states, A and B, and I go from A to B through an irreversible transformation (1) or a reversible transformation (2), aren't the entropy variations equal for (1) and (2)? I assume this because entropy variation only depends on the initial and final states, am I right?

So why, if I'm considering a transformation in an isolated system, the variation of entropy for a reversible transformation is $\Delta S=0$, but for an irreversible one, it is $\Delta S>0$ ? Shouldn't they be the same?

Also, if I consider Clausius integrals of this transformation from A to B, passing from (1) or (2), I obtain:

$\Delta S=\int \left(\frac {dQ}T\right)_2 > \int \left(\frac {dQ}T\right)_1$

And the integral calculated along (1) doesn't correspond with $\Delta S$ from A to B along (1), right? $\Delta S$ of an irreversible transformation should always be calculated along a reversible transformation from A to B.

So overall, why is $\Delta S>0$ for an isolated and irreversible transformation?

I hope you can understand my doubt, I'm not studying these topics in English, and it was really difficult to express my question.

Comment: To get to the same final state using a reversible path, the system can not be treated as isolated.  You will have to allow heat transfer with the surroundings in the case of the alternate  reversible path.

Comment: @ChetMiller thank you so much, now I can finally understand

Answer (score 1):

> aren't the entropy variations equal for (1) and (2)? I assume this
> because entropy variation only depends on the initial and final
> states, am I right?

Yes you are correct.

> So why, if I'm considering a transformation in an isolated system, the
> variation of entropy for a reversible transformation is $\Delta S=0$,
> but for an irreversible one, it is $\Delta S>0$ ? Shouldn't they be
> the same?

The change in entropy between the two equilibrium states for any process is defined for a reversible transfer of heat by the equation

$$\Delta S_{AB}= \int_A^B\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T}$$

Where $T$ is the equilibrium temperature of the system. *This applies regardless of whether the actual process is reversible and whether or not there actually is heat transfer occurring.*

But there are two potential components of the variation in entropy: (1) Entropy transfer across the boundary between the system and surroundings and (2) entropy generation as the result of the process being irreversible. So

$$\Delta S_{AB}= \int_A^B\frac{dQ}{T_B}+\sigma_{AB}$$

The first term on the right is the entropy transfer at the boundary where $T_B$ in the temperature at the boundary between the system and the surroundings where heat $Q$ crosses and $\sigma_{AB}$ is the entropy generated *if the process is irreversible*.

So combining the two equations we have

$$\Delta S_{AB}=\int_A^B\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T}=\int_A^B\frac{dQ}{T_B}+\sigma_{AB}$$

Now, for an isolated system which by definition involves no heat or work transfer, $dQ/T_{B}=0$. If the process is reversible, then $\sigma_{AB}=0$ and we are left with

$$\Delta S_{AB}=\int_A^B\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T}=0$$

On the other hand, if the process is irreversible $\sigma_{AB}\ne0$ and we have

$$\Delta S_{AB}=\int_A^B\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T}=\sigma_{AB}\gt0$$

Which tells us we can calculate the entropy generated during an irreversible process by assuming any convenient reversible process connecting states A and B that satisfies the first law and which need not bear any resemblance to the actual process. A typical example is the free expansion of an ideal gas in an isolated system.

Hope this helps.